# simplify this django query

Tags: python, django

I have a Post object that can contact PostTypes of 'Articles' or 'Organization'. Posts have a field called approved, a field called published and there is also a history that keep track of all the previous versions of the Post. I want to get the latest approved and published Posts.

```
class Post(Published, models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    posttype = models.ForeignKey(PostType)
    organization = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True,blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords() # django-simple-history   
    status = models.IntegerField(
        choices=settings.STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=settings.DRAFT_STATUS, # or can be settings.PUBLISHED_STATUS
        )

class PostType(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Here is a pictorial representation:

[image: sdf]

Here is my convoluted way of getting the latest approved and published Posts.

```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # Get me all the posttypes except for articles
    exclude_articles = PostType.objects.exclude(slug__icontains="article")

    # get me approved organizations (i.e. not articles) that are approved
    orgs = Post.objects.filter(approved = True).filter(posttype__in=exclude_articles)
    result = []

    # for each of the organization, get me the latest published history
    for org in orgs:
        result.append(org.history.filter(status=settings.PUBLISHED_STATUS).order_by('-modified_date')[0].history_object)

    context['form'].fields['organization'].queryset = result
    return context
```

The above way of doing this return a list instead of queryset (which is another problem). Can we simplify this and get a queryset?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't tried this refactoring so take it and use it as a pointer!

First, you don't need to chain the `.filter()` calls. You can "just" use CSV style in one filter call that and using the [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object then you can do a negated query in your filter.

Then we can move on to using relationships, now I haven't used Django Simple History, but i'm guessing it works with normal FK traversal.

So that would mean that you could access the history status via a normal `history__status` accessor and lastly, using the [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) method will allow you to get a list back with just 1 or several values directly from the DB thus avoiding doing the `res.append(org[0].something)`.

So, as I said, I haven't tried this code out but it should give you a pointer in the right direction.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    result = Post.objects.filter(approved = True, ~Q(posttype__slug_icontains="article"), \
                                history__status=settings.PUBLISHED_STATUS) \
                                .order_by('-modified_date').values('history_object')

    context['form'].fields['organization'].queryset = result
    return context
```

Now this makes no sense whatsoever, and it's really hard to read so I would suggest that you move this to the `Post`s model manager.

```
class PostManager(models.ModelManager):

    def approved_and_published_posts(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(approved = True, ~Q(posttype__slug_icontains="article"), \
        history__status=settings.PUBLISHED_STATUS) \
        .order_by('-modified_date').values('history_object')


class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()
```

Then in your view you could always do this:

```
orgs = Post.objects.approved_and_published_posts()
```

Hope this helps and at least points you in the right direction!

Comment: I haven't used django-simple-history either, but I don't think this is right. You're returning all matching posts and trying to order them by `modified_date` (which doesn't exist on `Post`). What the OP wants is, for each matching `Post`, to get the latest history entry as determined by the `modified_date` on the `history` items.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Absolutely, you're right! As I said, this should be taken as a pointer, I know it isn't 100% correct. That being said, he could always use `.latest()` somewhere in there to get the latest history entry.